# How to to perform Linq query of a list with another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List of Member class, members. The Member class has the following properties:

MemberId : string
MemberName : string
DateOfBirth : DateTime

```
List<Member> members = FindMembers();
```

I have a separate List of MemberId, as shown below.

```
List<string> memberIds = GetTeenAgeMemberIds();
```

Now I have to query the Members list with the values in the memberIds  List. Please let me know how could I do this using Linq.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following LINQ query:

```
var result = members.Where(m => memberIds.Contains(m.MemberId)).
    ToArray();
```

Alternatively:

```
var result = (from m in members
              join id in memberIds on m.MemberId equals id
              select m).ToArray();
```

Or if you prefer method chains:

```
var result = members.Join(memberIds, m => m.MemberId, id => id, (m, id) => m).
    ToArray();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use an Array. I have to get the filtered list as List<Member>, since I have to use this list to bind a gridview. Thanks

Comment: @user466663 Then just replace the `ToArray()` calls to `ToList()`.

Answer (score 0):

Make the target list an array or something obviously managed, use Contains on it to compare the MemberId you have with the list you have.